# Microsoft Graph Toolkit - just trying to load without an error

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

Trying to load MGT in a Javascript application via:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/mgt/dist/bundle/mgt-loader.js"></script>
<mgt-msal2-provider client-id="********-****-****-****-*************"></mgt-msal2-provider>
```

that immediately generates an error in the console. I copied the client-id from the Azure Portal for the Graph Applicate I created. went through the permissions very carefully.

Really, not even sure how to troubleshoot this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
    at Function.getDocumentDirection (mgt.es6.js:186)
    at HTMLElement.handleDirectionChanged (mgt.es6.js:186)
    at new MgtBaseComponent (mgt.es6.js:186)
    at new MgtBaseProvider (mgt.es6.js:186)
    at new MgtMsal2Provider (mgt.es6.js:1775)
```

Comment: Are you able to generate the logged out state at all, or does this error happen even previous to that? Checkout this fiddle working here:
https://jsfiddle.net/7qacrgt4/3/